# Switch to viewport by name?

Tags: vimscript, buffers

Typing `:buffers` gives a list of loaded buffers. Can I switch to a viewport that views one of those buffers by name?

I know that `:buffer NAME` will load the named buffer in the current viewport. But I would rather type something like `:viewport NAME` and to have the cursor move to whatever viewport is currently viewing the named buffer, without changing which buffers are loaded. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to set the `switchbuf` option to "useopen" and then use `:sbuffer NAME` instead of `:buffer` to move your cursor to a window that has this buffer loaded.

See `:help switchbuf` for more information on valid values, this is definitely the setting that handles the behviour you want.

Comment: This works: `:set switchbuf+=useopen` followed by `:sbuffer NAME`.